# iframe with https video url not working

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to define iframe src as an https, but it's not working.
thanks

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRSAmekqRBo">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know youtube gives you iframe embed code right below the video that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Siri try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7aeadvv/).

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iRSAmekqRBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can get the embed code in youtube by clicking share then select the embed tab. Hope this works.